# How to deal with/escape whitespace in file path for bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, filesystem-access

I am passing a file path to bibtex via the command

```
\bibliography{/Users/MyName/Dropbox/Bibliography Both/bibo}
```

However, with that whitespace in place (that one's silly just for demo purposes), BibTex complains:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014)
The top-level auxiliary file: auxfile.aux
White space in argument---line 47 of file auxfile.aux
 : \bibdata{'/Users/MyName/Dropbox/Bibliography
 :                                              Both/bibo'}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
The style file: ecta.bst
I found no database files---while reading file auxfile.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "RefWorks:13"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Is there away to escape the whitespace. Either

```
\
```

or double/single quotes did not work.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Simplest and universal approach: Don't use whitespace in your file names. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13311129#13311129 ;-)

Comment: BibTeX is a quite old program and doesn't support spaces in file names. Sorry.

Comment: Is BibLatex the newer thing then? Anyway, BibTex is amazing in so many regards so happy to do away with those.. :)

Comment: BibLaTeX with Biber is newer and more capable. However, I wouldn't switch to support weird characters in file names since those are A Very Bad Thing in any case. (And, yes, a space *is* weird when it occurs in a file name.)

Comment: You could try using a relative path and a (sym/hard)link. I have never tried it, though.

Comment: Haha ok I will avoid the weirdness in my filesystem then. Well, I have just spent a fair deal of time figuring out my bibliography with some incredibly friendly texexchangers, so I shall wait until after submission and switch to Biber then and will post a Q&A style on it.